# Immutable.js deleteIn not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have been trying to solve this problem, but there is probably something of Immutable.js  that I don't catch. I hope somebody can help me to understand.

I have a test like this:

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
import {expect} from 'chai';

import {setInitial,
        addAtListOfMembers,
        removeAtListOfMembers
        } from '../src/core';


      describe('removeAtListOfMembers', () => {

        it('remove a member to the list of members', () => {
          const state = Map({
            removing: 3,
            infos : Map(),
            members: Map({
                1:Map({
                    userName:'René',
                    date:'12/02/2016'
                }),
                2:Map({
                    userName:'Jean',
                    date:'10/03/2016'
                }),
                3:Map({
                    userName:'Elene',
                    date:'05/01/2016'
                })
              })
          });
          const nextState = removeAtListOfMembers(state);

          expect(nextState).to.equal(Map({
            infos : Map(),
            members: Map({
                1:Map({
                    userName:'René',
                    date:'12/02/2016'
                }),
                2:Map({
                    userName:'Jean',
                    date:'10/03/2016'
                })
              })
          }));
        });
      });
});
```

...witch tests this funtion:

```
export function removeAtListOfMembers(state) {
  const members = state.get('members');

  const removing = state.get('removing');

  return state
        .deleteIn(['members'], removing)
        .remove('removing');
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have tryed everything.... changing the line to make it work, but I don't get the item number 3 deleted.

What's wrong? Somebody to help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
export function removeAtListOfMembers(state) {
  const members = state.get('members');

  const removing = state.get('removing');

  return state
        .deleteIn(['members', String(removing) ])
        .remove('removing');
}
```

Your code has two issues:

- `deleteIn` takes a single `keyPath` argument, which in your case is `[ 'members' ]`. The second argument (`removing`) is ignored, so the result is that the entire `members` map is deleted; instead, `removing` should become part of the key path.
- `removing` is a `Number`, but because you're creating a `Map` from a JS object, its keys will be `String`'s (this is mentioned in [the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) as well):

  > Keep in mind, when using JS objects to construct Immutable Maps, that JavaScript Object properties **are always strings**

So you need to convert `removing` to a `String` when passing it to `deleteIn`.