# Issues with Redux - Adding & Removing Items From State

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, immutable.js

I'm working on a shopping cart and I'm trying to wrap my head around two problems with my app:

**Adding items to the store is overwriting previous items in the store:**

Initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  items: {},
  showCart: false
};
```

Add to Cart Reducer:

**Problem**: This works for adding an item to the cart, but when I go to add another item in the cart, it overwrites the previous item. Why would that be / How do I preserve the items in the previous state?

```
let addToCartState = {...state,
  items: {
    [action.id]: {
      id: action.id,
        color: action.product_selection.color,
        size: action.product_selection.size,
        quantity: 1
       }
     },
  showCart: true
}
return state.merge(addToCartState);
```

Remove All From Cart Reducer:

**Problem**: This seems to work, but I can't seem to grab data from the state map. I can't seem to call "state.cart.items" (see mapStateToProps) like I can on my other states.

```
let removeFromCartState = {...state,
  items: {
    ...state.items
  },
  showCart: true
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state.cart);
  console.log("");
  return { products: state.products, items: state.cart.items }
}
```

state.cart:

```
Map {size: 8, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
  size: 8
  __altered: false
  __hash: undefined
  __ownerID: undefined
  _root: ArrayMapNode
  entries: Array(8)
    0: Array(2)
      0: "items"
      1: Map
        size: 0
   ...
```

^ No items now (size: 0, was 1 after the previous reducer); do I need to use something like fromJS to parse this now or should I not have to do that?

Edit - combineReducers:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import app from './appReducer';
import products from './productsReducer';
import cart from './cartReducer';
import user from './userReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  app: app,
  products: products,
  cart: cart,
  user: user
});
```

Comment: Do you have a `combineReducers` set up and how is it structured? For the "Add to Cart Reducer" you must copy the nested objects as well. So `{...state, items: { ...state.items, /* etc.*/ } }`

Comment: I just tried doing the copying of nested objects and I'm oddly still getting the same thing with only one product being able to be in the cart at a time. I do have a combineReducers and it's just like:

`export default combineReducers({
  app: app,
  products: products,
  cart: cart,
  user: user
});`

Comment: You don't have to merge the new state with the old state if you're using the spread operator (the `...state` and `...state.items`). That's essentially copying everything and when you update the values to the keys in the objects that overwrites the previous ones. Also, update your code to include the `combineReducers` if you have one. That should help me provide you a better answer. Also if code is within separate files separate them. A chunk of code makes it look like it's in the same file.

Comment: @KeithAlpichi Added my combineReducers, not sure if that's any help or not. And that's what I thought with the spread operator, but it's not actually retaining the data from the previous state with that for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you're treating Immutable.js objects like regular JavaScript objects instead of using the built-in Immutable.js features intended for the tasks you're performing.

> **Problem:** This works for adding an item to the cart, but when I go to add another item in the cart, it overwrites the previous item. Why would that be / How do I preserve the items in the previous state?

Let's take a look at your code:

```
let addToCartState = { ...state,
  items: { [action.id]: { /* ... */ } },
  showCart: true
};
```

The spread operator (`...`) does a "shallow" merge. What your code is doing, essentially, is this:

```
let addToCartState = shallowCopy(state);
addToCartState.items = { [action.id]: { /* ... */ } };
addToCartState.showCart = true;
```

In other words, it "overwrites the previous item" because you're replacing the `items` property with a new object with only one item. One solution is to merge `items` yourself:

```
const addToCartState = { ...state,
  items: { ...state.items,
    [action.id]: { /* ... */ },
  },
  showCart: true,
};
```

...but since you're using Immutable.js, you shouldn't do that. You should use its built-in [`mergeDeep`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeDeep) method:

```js
function addToCart(prevState, action) {
  const addToCartState = {
    items: {
      [action.id]: {
        color: action.product_selection.color,
        // ...
      },
    },
    showCart: true,
  };
  return prevState.mergeDeep(addToCartState);
}

let state = Immutable.fromJS({ items: {} });
console.log('Original state:', state);

console.log('Add blue thing');
state = addToCart(state, {
  id: '123',
  product_selection: { color: 'blue' },
});

console.log('State is now:', state);

console.log('Add green thing');
state = addToCart(state, {
  id: '456',
  product_selection: { color: 'green' },
});

console.log('State is now:', state);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

---

> **Problem:** This seems to work, but I can't seem to grab data from the state map. I can't seem to call "state.cart.items" (see mapStateToProps) like I can on my other states.

`state` is not a "plain" JavaScript object, it's an Immutable.Map. You can't access its values like ordinary object properties. One solution is convert it to a plain object using [`toJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/toJS), then retrieve its properties (and sub-properties) like usual. An alternative, which will be preferable if your state object is potentially large, is to retrieve the values using Immutable.js' [`get`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/get) and [`getIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/getIn) (for "deep" properties). With the latter you'll have to use `toJS` on the individual values if they're also Immutable objects. You can see both approaches below.

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const obj = state.toJS();
  return { products: obj.products, items: obj.cart.items };
}

// or...

function mapStateToPropsAlt(state) {
  return {
    products: state.get('products').toJS(),
    items: state.getIn(['cart', 'items']).toJS(),
  };
}

const state = Immutable.fromJS({
  products: [ '¯\\_(ツ)_/¯' ],
  cart: {
    items: {
      '123': { id: '123', color: 'blue', /* ... */ },
    },
  },
});

console.log('mapStateToProps(state) =>', mapStateToProps(state));
console.log('mapStateToPropsAlt(state) =>', mapStateToPropsAlt(state));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Jordan, you just made my day. Phenomenal explanation that I can't thank you enough; mergeDeep did the trick and I finally understand Immutable a bit. Thank you!!!!

Comment: P.S. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? @jordan-running 's `get` code above works and when in the cart reducer I can do: `state.getIn(['items'])` . But for some reason I can't do `state.delete(["items", action.id])`.

Comment: @albaba It will help to read the docs. [`delete`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/delete), like `get`, takes a single value, e.g. `state.delete('items')`. To do a "deep" delete you need to use [`deleteIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/deleteIn).

Comment: yeah the docs are failing me right now. deleteIn isn't working in any of these variations: `state.deleteIn(['items', action.id])`, `state.deleteIn([state.get('items')), action.id])`, `state.deleteIn([state.get('items'), String(state.get('items', action.id))])` (per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37628337/1778314)) @jordan-running

Comment: @albaba I can't reproduce this; it [works fine here](https://codepen.io/jrunning/pen/mmoYPo?editors=0012). Make sure that the value of `action.id` and the value of the Immutable.Map's key are both what you expect. Don't forget that an Immutable.Map can have any type of value as a key, whereas JavaScript property names are always coerced to strings. `let key = 123; Immutable.Map({ [key]: 'foo' })` will produce a Map with the string key `'123'`, whereas `let key = 123; Immutable.Map().set(key, 'foo')` will produce a Map with the Number key `123`.